# Normals to a star-shaped region (Evans' PDE)

Tags: real-analysis

I'm finding some problems in undestanding the proof of the following statement that I found on L.Evans' PDE (pag. 515).

*If $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open star-shaped region with $\partial U\in C^1$, then $x\cdot\nu(x)\ge0$ $\forall x\in \partial U$*

Where $\nu$ denotes the outwards pointing normal.

In the proof he says

*Since $\partial U$ is $C^1$, if $x\in\partial U$ then for each $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$ and $y\in\bar{U}$ imply 
$$\nu(x)\cdot\frac{y-x}{|y-x|}\le\varepsilon$$*

But I do not understand why this inequality follows from the regularity of the boundary.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If $y$ is close to $x$ the vector $y - x$ is almost tangent to $\partial U$ at $x$. Hence its inner product with the normal can be made small.

Comment: Yes, this is clear from an intuitive point of view, but I would like to see a formal justification of this fact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume without loss that $\textbf{x} = \textbf{0}$. By definition of $C^1$ boundary, near $\textbf{0}$ we can find a coordinates system and a $C^1$ function $f$ such that

1. $\partial U = \{(\textbf{y'}, y_n) : y_n = f(\textbf{y'})\},$
2. $U = \{(\textbf{y'},y_n) : y_n < f(\textbf{y'})\},$
3. $f(\textbf{0'}) = 0$,
4. $\nabla f(\textbf{0'}) = \textbf{0'}$.

Then for $\textbf{y'}$ close to $\textbf{0'}$, $$\nu(\textbf{0}) \cdot \frac{(\textbf{y'},f(\textbf{y'}))}{\sqrt{y_1^2 + \dots + y_{n-1}^2 + f(\textbf{y'})^2}} = \frac{f(\textbf{y'})}{|\textbf{y}|} = \frac{1}{|\textbf{y}|}\Big(f(\textbf{0'}) + \nabla f(\textbf{0'})\cdot\textbf{y'} + \mathcal{O}(|\textbf{y}|^2)\Big) = \mathcal{O}(|\textbf{y}|).$$